# Windows 11 Taskbar replacement that will dock on the left

Tags: windows-11, taskbar

Ever since, I have been able to, my taskbar has been to the left and hidden. The reason being there is more space horizontally than vertically.  And it causes less interference with programs where I have to reach the bottom of the screen.

Windows 11 only supports it on the bottom.  It seems you can tweak it to go to the top.  This is a deal breaker for me.  I am absolutely not moving to Windows 11 with this retrograde step. Why would a developer expect me to break decades of habit ?

Are there any replacements for taskbars that will work on Windows 11 and will dock on the left ?

Comment: Did you see: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/600588/windows-11-taskbar.html ?

Comment: I commend your attention to the registry hack at https://pureinfotech.com/move-taskbar-top-side-windows-11/