# Third-party replacement for Windows 11 taskbar

Tags: windows-11, taskbar

Are there third-party replacements for Windows 11 Taskbar? Like, idk, using Linux taskbar instead of windows?

- There are actually many start menu replacements (AllIsBack, OpenShell) but none of them replaces taskbar
- There is [this questions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/83630/windows-11-taskbar-replacement-that-will-dock-on-the-left). But the focus of that question is actually how to dock existing windows 11 taskbar. I.e. not what is asked here
- There are multiple third-party software that switches Windows 11 taskbar to Windows 10 and then tweaking it (ExplorerPatcher, 7+ taskbar tweaker). Those also don't count.

Comment: You keep on saying what doesn't count, but not **why** they don't count. Some of the programs you mentioned are modifying the Taskbar to things the Windows default taskbar doesn't do, which I would call "replacing the taskbar". What exactly is it that you're looking in the "3d party Taskbar" to look like or be able to do?

Comment: Yes the main point for me is that I need multi-row taskbar (dozen documents open, I need to see them all with names). None of the solutions do this I think.